# How to restrict downloads only to users logged in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to create a code that will download a file only if the user is logged into Wordpress.

Within a Wordpress installation I have the following:

```
$file = '../../documents/file.zip';
while (ob_get_level()) {
ob_end_clean();
}
header('Content-Type: application/x-download');
header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.zip"');
die(readfile($file));
exit;
```

That code works and downloads a file that is located outside the "public_html" folder.

When I include the following at the beginning to first verify if the user is logged in, it gives me an error:

```
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
require('../wp-blog-header.php');
if(!is_user_logged_in()) : 
wp_redirect(site_url('/wp-login.php').'?redirect_to=' . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); 
endif;
```

How could the user have to be logged in to download a file without having to use plugins?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use is_user_logged_in() to check user login or not with include require('wp-load.php'); try to below code

```
require('wp-load.php');

if(is_user_logged_in()) { 
    $file = '../../documents/file.zip';
    while (ob_get_level()) {
    ob_end_clean();
    }
    header('Content-Type: application/x-download');
    header('X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="file.zip"');
    die(readfile($file));
    exit;   
}else{
    wp_redirect(site_url('/wp-login.php').'?redirect_to=' . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. @ErickEstevez if you like post then vote for post

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use to verify that a person should be able to download a file. The code to actually send the file is after this code which verifies that they are authorized to get the file and are logged in.

Depending on your site you may not use/need role checking and/or the administrator checking.

```
require('wp-load.php');
if(empty($_GET['name'])                  OR  // no file nickname passed in the URL or
   !array_key_exists($_GET['name'],$map) OR  // not a nickname we recognize or
   !is_user_logged_in()) {                   // user is not logged in to WordPress

    header('Location: http://example.com/');
    exit;

}  // end of if no file passed or not logged in

$roles = wp_get_current_user()->roles;

//
// user does not have the proper role and is not an administrator
//

if (!in_array('somerole',$roles) AND
    !in_array('administrator',$roles)) {

    header('Location: http://example.com/');
    exit;

}  // end of if user does not have the proper role
```